# Do network drivers for Ubuntu 14.04 on Optiplex 7060 exist?

Tags: 14.04, networking, drivers, ethernet

The [Ubuntu HW page](https://certification.ubuntu.com/hardware/201709-25772/) lists two devices: https://certification.ubuntu.com/catalog/component/pci/1d6a%3Ad108/ and https://certification.ubuntu.com/catalog/component/pci/8086%3A15bb/.

Installing the most recent official Ubuntu 14.04 release, 14.04.5 LTS, gets me "No network interfaces detected" during install.

I have found the ["Intel Ethernet Adapter Complete Driver Pack"](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/22283/Ethernet-Intel-Ethernet-Adapter-Complete-Driver-Pack?product=82185), but it appears to be source code only for Ubuntu.

The output of 'sudo lshw -C network' is:

```
 *-network UNCLAIMED
    description: Ethernet controller
    product: Intel Corporation
    product: Intel Corporation
    physical id: 1f.6
    bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
    version: 10
    width: 32 bits
    clock: 33 MHz
    capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
    configuration: latency=0
    resources: memory:91100000-9111ffff
```

Because it solved a similar problem with the Optiplex 7040, I tried adding the latest kernel updates from https://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty-updates/amd64/ and the corresponding dependencies:

- linux-image-extra-4.4.0-134-generic_4.4.0-134.160_14.04.1_amd64.deb
- linux-headers-4.4.0-134_4.4.0-134.160~14.04.1_all.deb
- linux-headers-4.4.0-134-generic_4.4.0-134.160_14.04.1_amd64.deb
- linux-headers-generic-lts-xenial_4.4.0.134.114_amd64.deb
- linux-image-4.4.0-134-generic_4.4.0-134.160_14.04.1_amd64.deb
- iucode-tool_1.0.1-1_amd64.deb
- intel-microcode_3.20180807a.0ubuntu0.14.04.1_amd64.deb
- amd64-microcode_3.20180524.1~ubuntu0.14.04.2+really20130710.1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
- linux-image-generic-lts-xenial_4.4.0.134.114_amd64.deb
- linux-generic-lts-xenial_4.4.0.134.114_amd64.deb

Now when I run 'sudo lshw -C network', I get odd behavior where "PCI (sysfs)" appears momentarily, then disappears, replaced by a new prompt (EDIT: after rebooting, it gives the same output as above). It also seems not to have helped with the network driver.

The result of 'lspci -nnk | grep 0200 -A3' is:

```
00:1f.6 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:15bb] (rev 10)
        Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:085a]
```

Comment: What is the output of `sudo lshw -C network`?

Comment: I will fit it above.

Comment: May we also see: `lspci -nnk | grep 0200 -A3`

Comment: Sure - Added above!

Comment: Did you also install update `linux-firmware` from trusty-updates? It seems to me that the Intel e1000 should work which is provided with kernel 4.4. Maybe someone smarter than I can help out.

Comment: Is that linux-firmware-nonfree? https://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty-updates/amd64/kernel/linux-firmware-nonfree I will try it, thanks!

Comment: I added that package and still get the same results when I try 'sudo lshw -C network': "Unclaimed".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is, yes, a driver exists, but currently only in source code form. Here is what I did:

Downloaded the driver sources from Intel here: https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/22283/Ethernet-Intel-Ethernet-Adapter-Complete-Driver-Pack...

Updated to the most recent kernel backport packages with "sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-lts-xenial"

Updated gcc to a more recent version with 'retpoline' support (https://lwn.net/Articles/744287/), to match the newer kernel packages (before I did this, I got the following error):

```
version magic '4.4.0-145-generic SMP mod_unload modversions ' should be '4.4.0-134-generic SMP mod_unload modversions retpoline'
insmod: ERROR: could not insert module ./e1000e.ko: Invalid module format
```

Built e1000e-3.4.0.2 from the Intel sources, put it onto the machine via USB stick, replaced the existing e1000e driver under /lib/modules, and added a line with 'e1000e' to /etc/modules.

Added to /etc/network/interfaces:

```
auto em1
iface em1 inet dhcp
```